# Canon MP495 Scanner not working

Tags: 12.04, canon, scanner

Running 12.04, installed and updated latest drivers for MP495 but nothing stil.

latest drivers provided here:
https://code.launchpad.net/~michael-gruz/+archive/canon-trunk/+packages

Followed this guide to the letter:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602839&page=11

Xsane and simple scan do not work. I have tried various other programs and have nothing...
People are saying it works well with 11.10, so I don't know what the deal is with 12.04.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need this printer for my out-of-home business, and I really don't want to switch back windows just for a freaking scanner to function.

Why don't these companies realise ubuntu users need to print things too?!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for sharing the link to the latest drivers. I have MP287 and I was looking for the correct drivers to detect the scanner.

I installed `scangearmp-common_1.80-0~11~precise1_i386.deb` and `scangearmp-mp280series_1.80-0~11~precise1_i386.deb` from there and it all works now.

**Running `/usr/bin/scangearmp` detects the scanner and I was able to scan a few documents as well.**

Perhaps this will work for you, as well.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. I have a Canon MP495. And I am running Kubuntu 12.04.

I followed your description and installed first `"scangearmp-common_1.80-0~11~precise1_i386.deb"` and second

```
"scangearmp-mp490series_1.80-0~11~precise1_i386.deb"
```

`Running /usr/bin/scangearmp` runs as described.

Answer (score 0):

### Scanner Installation

Download the scanner driver from the [official Cannon site](http://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp495.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)), named "Linux IJ Scanner Driver"

Got file MP495series-scanner_driver.tar

Explode downloaded tar

```
tar xvf MP495series-scanner_driver.tar

cd MP495series-scanner_driver
```

Explode Scan Gear MP installable

```
tar zxvf scangearmp-mp495series-1.60-1-deb.tar.gz

cd scangearmp-mp495series-1.60-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

---

### Scanner Usage:

## Using Scanner from command prompt

scangearmp
The [Select Scanner] dialog is displayed.

From the list, select the model you want to use, and then click [OK].

To use this machine with a USB connection, select "Canon MP495 series (libusb:port number)." To use this machine with a network connection, select "Canon MP495 series (MAC address).

The models displayed in the list consist of USB-connected scanners and network-connected scanners.
When you start ScanGear for the first time in a network connection or if the scanner that you want to use is not displayed in the list, click [Update Scanner List] to run a network search.

## Using Scanner from GIMP

Launch GIMP

Select [Create] -> [ScanGear MP...] from the [File] menu in GIMP.

The [Select Scanner] dialog is displayed.

If Ubuntu does not display [ScanGear MP...], first exit GIMP, execute the command below, and then restart GIMP.
[user@zzz /yyy]$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/scangearmp /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins

From the list, select the model you want to use, and then click [OK].

To use this machine with a USB connection, select "Canon MP495 series (libusb:port number)." To use this machine with a network connection, select "Canon MP495 series (MAC address).

*Credits*: Official manual guidemp495series-sd-1.60-1_en